# Using Zorn's Lemma in a proof

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help in the proof of the following theorem:

If $V = \text{span}(S)$, $S$ a nonempty subset of $V$, then there is a basis $S_{0}$ of $V$ such that $S_{0} \subseteq{S}$.

Here's my attempt to solve:

$\text{Proof}:$ Let $\Sigma = \{ T : T \subseteq S, \text{T is a L.I. subset of V}$} ordered by inclusion, i.e, $ A \leq B \iff A \subseteq B$. Let $\{S_{i}\}_{i \in I}$ an arbitrary chain in $\Sigma$. Then, defining $\tilde{S} = \bigcup_{i \in I}S_{i}$, we have that $S_{i} \subseteq \tilde{S}$, $\forall i \in I$. Therefore $\tilde{S}$ is a upper bound. Thus, follows by Zorn's Lemma that  $\exists S_{0} \in \Sigma$ such that $S_{0}$ is maximal. Since $S_{0} \subseteq S$ is maximal and LI, follows that $S_{0}$ is a basis for $V$.

Is this wrong? What is missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your general idea is correct , only a small part that you have to be careful.

Comment: You have to show that $\tilde {S}$ belongs to $\Sigma$ in order to use zorns lemma.

Comment: But $\tilde{S}$ is a union of subsets of $\Sigma$.

Comment: with certain property , that $T$ is linearly independent. So in order for $\tilde{S}$ to be in $\Sigma$ you have to show that is LI  and there is were you need $S_{i}$ to form a chain.

Comment: It's not a union of subsets of $\Sigma$. It's a union of _elements_ of $\Sigma$. Since the elements of $\Sigma$ are subsets of $S$, it is immediate that $\tilde{S}$ is a subset of $S$. But only the linearly independent subsets of $S$ are elements of $\Sigma$. So to know that $\tilde{S}$ is an upper bound for the chain, you need to show that $\tilde{S}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: I see. How can I show that a finite union of L.I subsets is L.I.?